Ackermann function in risc-v cannot get the correct value, stuck in infinite loop
Consider this C code,
  if (n == 0) {
    return m + 1;
  } else if (m == 0) {
    return ackermann(n - 1, 1);
  } else {
    return ackermann(n - 1, ackermann(n, m - 1));
  }
}
int main() {
  int result = ackermann(3, 4);
  printf("%d", result);
}

in RISC-V Assembly:
.globl main

.text

main:
    addi a3, a3, 3
    addi a4, a4, 4
    
    
    jal ra, ackermann
    # use s0 for result variable
    
    addi a1, a0, 0
    addi a0, zero, 1 
    ecall
    addi a0, zero, 10
    ecall
    
ackermann:
    addi sp, sp, -16
    sw a4, 8(sp)        
    sw a3, 4(sp)
    sw ra, 0(sp)
    
    bne a3, zero, n_notzero #n!=0 opposite of n==0 query
    
    addi a0, a4, 1  #m+1
    
    jal ra, return#return m+1
    
n_notzero:
    bne a4, zero, m_notzero #m!=0
    
    addi a3, a3, -1
    addi a4, zero, 1
    jal ra, ackermann
    jal ra, return   #return ackermann(n-1, 1)
    
m_notzero:
    #return ackermann(n-1, ackermann(n,m-1))
    #ackermann(n,m-1)
    
    addi a4, a4, -1
    jal ra, ackermann
    
    
    add t0, a0, zero  #return(ackermann(3,3)) = 2 save into t0, result is in a0 when coming back
    add a4, t0, zero    
    lw a3, 4(sp)    
    addi a3, a3, -1     #n-1
    jal ra, ackermann # ackermann(n-1, ackermann(n, m-1))
    
    jal ra, return
    
return:
    lw ra, 0(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 16
    jalr zero, ra, 0

I am trying to translate to risc-v but my program gets caught in an endless loop.
And I don't know why, I basically translated it good as far as I know but somehow it still won't give me the correct output (should be 125 for the ackermann function for A(3,4))

Stack & register usage is off.  So, you might consider using the standard  calling convention because the details of how registers are shared between separate fiunction invocations are worked out.  To create/use yout own custom calling convention you need to work those details out.

So basically i need to somehow work with my stack ? I am considering the calling convention but still i can‘t get out of the endless state of my program

When you're debugging, compare the assembly and C versions line by line.
